# File.file?() and File::directory?()

Tags: ruby, syntax

Newbie question here, but in Ruby, why would File.file?() and File::directory?() be called differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File::file?` and `File.file?` are equivalent, as are `File::directory?` and `File.directory?`. Both are methods belonging to the class, and may be invoked with either syntax.

Comment: I was using the reference link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_input_output.htm which was why I asked, just to make sure I wasn't missing something.  When I tried File.directory?() from the command line (irb), it didn't seem to process, while File.file?() does.  But it was because I was escaping the quotations without knowing it, leaving it hanging (e.g. File.directory?("/Users/")).  Got it - thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as a class method in Ruby. Ruby knows only one kind of method: regular instance methods. *Every* method on *every* object can be called with `::` instead of `.`. The only exception are methods that start with an uppercase letter, since in that case `::` will be interpreted as scope resolution for constants, not a method call. (Actually, to be precise, you can't call methods in Ruby, either. You can only send messages, and the system may (or may not) invoke a method in response to that message.)